# Adding divs in flex until overflow

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I would like my container to look like this:
[image: Sample]
Where each div goes onto the next line if it will cause an overflow.

But at the moment it looks like this:
[image: Sample 2]

My code:

```html
<div class="marker-cm">
    <div class="marker"> Fit-content width here </div>
    <div class="marker"> More fit-content width here </div>
    <div class="marker"> Text </div>
    <div class="marker"> Something here </div>
</div>
```

```css
.marker-cm{
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;
} 
.marker{
    height: 23px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 0px 7px;
    margin-right: 7px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: Add `flex-wrap: wrap;` to `.marker-cm`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In standard CSS, the `flex-wrap` property defaults to `nowrap` ([ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap)).

Override the default.

Add `flex-wrap: wrap` to the flex container.

(You may also need to add `flex-shrink: 0` to the flex items, to disable the default shrinking feature.)